# How to echo multiple select dropdown into a textarea with PHP

Tags: php, textarea, echo

I have working on this for hours and searched the net since last night but to no avail. I am trying to collect multiple options selected from a dropdown menu in a form and echo it into the textarea of the form on the next page.

I am able to echo the multiple options but cannot figure out how to echo the selectted options directly into the textarea of the form on the next page. Please help.

Here is the form..

```html
<html><head>
</head><body>
<center><form action="92.php" method="post">
<select name="cat[]" size="9" required multiple><option value="Africa">Africa</option>
<option value="App">App</option>
<option value="Art">Art</option></select><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form></center>
</body></html>
```

Here is the second form 92.php...

```html
<?php
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
foreach ($cat as $s) {
echo "<center><form action=max21.php method=post>
Your ID: <input class=text size=9 name=us type=text readonly><br /><br />
<textarea rows=4 cols=35 id=ans name=ans maxlength=140>$s</textarea><br /><br />
<input type=submit id=submit value=Submit></form></center>";
}
?>
```

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: This should work. Your question is not clear: 1) do you need one text area /form per selected option or 2) all selected options inside ONE textarea? 1) is working....

Comment: I need all selected options inside one text area. Right now, it is giving me 3 forms if I choose 3 options and 2 forms if I select 2 options. I want all the selected options inside a single text area so that I can then process it easily.

Comment: in that case - check answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<center><form action=max21.php method=post>
Your ID: <input class=text size=9 name=us type=text readonly><br /><br />
<textarea rows=4 cols=35 id=ans name=ans maxlength=140>
<?php
$cat = $_POST['cat'];


foreach ($cat as $s) {echo $s. ' ';
}



?>
</textarea><br /><br />
<input type=submit id=submit value=Submit></form></center>
```

This should work. Simple, start loop INSIDE textarea. The rest on 92.php page is ordinary HTML - no need to echo form.

Comment: Thanks a ton NeverMind. Please tell me how to show each selected option on a new line inside the text area. Thanks a lot really.

Comment: No problem - echo $s. "\n"  (instead empty space - new line char as a separator)

Comment: It's not happening. I am using a comma instead. If you know it or figure it out later then let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out. I just added a line space in the empty space between the two colons.